# Mongodb is too slow on selecting big data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql, bigdata

I am using **Mongodb** in a **Nodejs** application. The database has 17 million documents. I want to select 1 million in one query with mongoose.

```js
const vehicles = await Vehicle.find({
  PassedTime: {
    $gte: startDate,
    $lte: endDate
  }
});
```

I've already created an index on PassedTime and set my mongodb profile on level 2 with `{slowms: 20, sampleRate: 0.42}`. But it takes many seconds. Same data in **Mysql/PHP** takes only 2 seconds (in another system with 256G SSD)! Is there something wrong? Can I do it faster with **Mongodb/Nodejs**?

Also I have 32GB memory, 4T HDD. Maybe it's all about HDD and SSD :")

Comment: ["When enabled, profiling has an effect on database performance, especially when configured with a 
profiling level
 of 2, or when using a low 
threshold
 value with a profiling level of 1. Profiling also consumes disk space, as it logs to both the 
system.profile
 collection and also the MongoDB 
logfile
. Carefully consider any performance and security implications before configuring and enabling the profiler on a production deployment."](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/#std-label-database-profiling-overhead).

Comment: Yeah, after profiling the performance got better. But I still believe it’s not fast enough. @rickhg12hs